# javascript keyboardEvent.code "BrowserSearch"

Tags: javascript

I am have an application that runs using phpdesktop. It utilizes chrome 57 which has presented numerous problems when running javascript. I am trying to trigger on a button press of a windows MCE remote control for the browser search button. I have confirmed when pressed on other capable browsers that is does return the event code as `"BrowserSearch"`. Is there a different way to trigger on this as the code below returns nothing to me. There is no `event.keyCode` (which is all chrome 57 likes) value listed for this particular button only value for `event.key` and `event.code`

```
<body onkeydown="remoteButton(event)">


function remoteButton(event){

    if(event.code === "BrowserSearch"){
        alert('Browser search button pressed');
    }

    if(event.key === "BrowserSearch"){
        alert('Browser search button pressed');
    }

}
```